# Why is powershell telling me I need .\ before pip

Tags: powershell, python-2.7, pip

I just installed `pip`, `distribute`, `nose` and `virtualenv` in windows using powershell. For some reason powershell makes me add `.\` before pip and nosetests? Does anyone know why?

I read the help in powershell and it talks about the correct path which I think I have. All are installed in `Python27/Scripts`... same path I'm using in Powershell.

Powershell gives me the "*doesnt recognize as cmlet*" etc then suggests I should use the `.\` before... When I use this it works.
Looked on here and couldn't find the answer so forgive me if this has been asked previously.

Comment: Can you do `$env:path` in the PowerShell session where you are trying this out and check that the directory that contains the `pip` script is included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the old command shell, PowerShell will not run programs or scripts in the current directory by default.

You should modify your path to include the specific directory or directories that you need to include.

I would advise against adding `.` to your path (which would make PowerShell behave more similarly to DOS) as this introduces a possible attack vector.

Comment: Thanks... but I already added the folder to the path that pip is in when running it... isnt this what your saying?